# URL rewriting removing question mark and replace it with slash

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite my URL from `edit.php?id=2` to `edit/id/2`?

Comment: you mean /edit/id/2 => edit.php?id=2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^edit/id/([0-9]+)/?$ edit.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It works but my styles.css and other images doesn't load coz the location has changed.

Comment: do you have other rules? what is the URL for the style.css?

Comment: I added a variable in my includes like <?php echo $currentdir;?>/niceforms.js but niceform.js generates img/0.png and img/0.png don't load.

Comment: and img/0.png is located in : `edit/id/`?

Comment: This should be the location of "img/0.png" in my php output.My img folder is the same location as edit.php
img/0.png but the result is
edit/id/img/0.png

Comment: I would recommend then to write that URL as /img/0.png so the script will look at the root level and not the sub folder: `<?php echo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $currentdir; ?>/niceforms.js`

Comment: oh i see...I'll try it.

Comment: what is the point of "`RewriteBase /`" ? The base ain't by default "`/`" ??

Comment: The RewriteBase directive explicitly sets the base URL for per-directory rewrites. As you will see below, RewriteRule can be used in per-directory config files (.htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need redirect from:

```
http://yoursite.com/subpage1/subpage2/?YOURSTRING=blabla
 ---------->
http://yoursite.com/subpage1/subpage2/
```

then in the beginning of `.htaccess`, insert:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} YOURSTRING=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

## If WordPress is not installed in root folder, then edit the fourth line like this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR-WORDPRESS-DIRECTORY/$1? [R=301,L]
```

p.s. if you want other redirection from **QUESTION MARK**, then use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15680832/2377343

Comment: Instead of putting a link to answer the question, could you write the answer here?